# How to use libFLAC to read FLAC tags in c#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Is there an .net c# wrapper for the libFLAC library? If not, how can I read FLAC tags using the libFLAC in a .net framework c# application? If neither, are there other opensource libraries to read flac tags in c#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cyber_sinh.aspx) that could be of use to you.

Comment: This article has been deleted since.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but in case somebody wants that specific information, here's the Wayback machine's link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20140122195044/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15332/Assembly-to-Read-and-Write-Ogg-Tags-Vorbis-FLAC-an

In accordance with StackOverflow rules and in case even that link above gets lost, here's the article's text and graphics, courtesy of "Cyber Sinh", developer of MetatOGGer, LyricWiki and the Xiph Media Encoder:

> For my freeware project, MetatOGGer, I needed a managed library to read and write tags contained in Ogg and FLAC streams. As I couldn't find any, I decided to write one myself.
>
> The codecs supported by this library include Vorbis, FLAC and Speex. Technical information about Ogg and FLAC files can also be gotten using this library.
>
> Text tags will be stored in a `SortedList<string, List<string>>` because you can have several identical tags such as "artist," etc. Picture tags will be stored in a collection of `ID3PictureFrame` with a `BitmapFrame` property (Windows Imaging Component).
>
> It's possible to read any raw data in an Ogg stream with the `OggPageReader` class.
>
> The use of `OggTagger` and `FlacTagger` is very easy. The source code is fully documented (in French). Here is the diagram for main classes:
>
> [image: Class diagram]

And the main code snippet:

```
using Luminescence.Xiph;
OggTagger ogg = new OggTagger(@"C:\Song.ogg");

// Load duration
DateTime time = new DateTime(0);
time = time.AddSeconds(ogg.Duration);

// Tags manipulation
string artist = ogg.Artist;
ogg.Title = "Creep";
SortedList<string, List<string>> tags = ogg.GetAllTags();
BitmapFrame cover = ogg.FlacArts[0].Picture;
```