# UltraID3 C# Lib, Coverart FLAC

Tags: c#, mp3

I use UltraID3 to get the Coverart of a mp3 file. Is there anyway that UltraID3 can do the same with flac files?

Or is there any other lib which can do this?
This is my MP3 code:

```
        UltraID3 myMp3 = new UltraID3();
        myMp3.Read(path);
        ID3FrameCollection myArtworkCollection =
        myMp3.ID3v2Tag.Frames.GetFrames(MultipleInstanceID3v2FrameTypes.ID3v23Picture);

        if (myArtworkCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            ID3v23PictureFrame ra = (ID3v23PictureFrame)myArtworkCollection[0];
            (ra.Picture).Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see UltraID3 only supports mp3.

I hope this helps: [How to use libFLAC to read FLAC tags in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287828/how-to-use-libflac-to-read-flac-tags-in-c)